# заполнение массива в цикле JQuery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

использую цикл JQuery `.each(function(){});`

Пример:

```js
var arr = [],
  check = '';
$('.commander_check').each(function() {
  if (
    $(this).prop('checked') && $(this).data('check') == '' ||
    !$(this).prop('checked') && $(this).data('check') == 'checked'
  ) {
    check = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
    arr[$(this).data('login')][check].push({
      'id': $(this).data('id'),
      'profit': $(this).data('profit')
    });
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="commander_check" data-check="checked" data-id="19727899" data-login="old" data-profit="ok">
```

Хочу получить массив вида `['old']['OFF'][['id'=>19727899, 'profit'=>'ok'],[...],...]`

но почему то вылетает ошибка `Cannot read property 'OFF' of undefined`

Задача: перебрать параметры чекбоксов и если `.prop('checked')` не совпадает с `$(this).data('check')`, то записать это в многомерный ассоциативный массив, вот собственно запись и не получается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var arr = {},
  check = '';
$('.commander_check').each(function() {
  var $self = $(this);

  if (
    $self.prop('checked') && $self.data('check') == '' ||
    !$self.prop('checked') && $self.data('check') == 'checked'
  ) {
    check = $self.prop('checked') ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
    // У вас не были объявлены следующие значения. По этому оно не могло добавить туда значения, так как этого объекта в массиве не было
    arr[$self.data('login')] = {};
    arr[$self.data('login')][check] = [];
    
    arr[$self.data('login')][check].push({
      'id': $self.data('id'),
      'profit': $self.data('profit')
    });
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="commander_check" data-check="checked" data-id="19727899" data-login="old" data-profit="ok">
```

Comment: данный код перезатирает arr[$self.data('login')] и  arr[$self.data('login')][check]

Comment: @Mcile, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: + добавил за ответ

Answer (score 1):

Может быть вы хотели сделать как-то так:

```js
var arr = [],
  check = '';
$('.commander_check').each(function() {
  if (
    $(this).prop('checked') && $(this).data('check') == '' ||
    !$(this).prop('checked') && $(this).data('check') == 'checked'
  ) {
    check = $(this).prop('checked') ? 'ON' : 'OFF';
    arr.push([$(this).data('login')], [check], {
      'id': $(this).data('id'),
      'profit': $(this).data('profit')
    });
  }
});
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="commander_check" data-check="checked" data-id="19727899" data-login="old" data-profit="ok">
```

У вас проблема в добавлении в массив.

Comment: я попробовал - но получился массив не тот который ожидался

Comment: @Mcile, судя по вашему ответу я понял, что именно вы имели в виду. Главное, что вы разобрались с тем, что проблема была в заполнении массива. Думаю, что стоит принять ответ Yurri , так как в контексте вопроса он вполне отвечает требованиям :)

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо [@Yuri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/20458/yuri) - наводка решения была правильно ориентированна по сторонам света, я лишь подкорректировал координаты выстрела

во первых поменял `var arr = []` на `var arr = {}`, как указал [@Yuri](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/20458/yuri)

и сделал проверку на пустые значения перед заполнением

```
if( ! ($(this).data('login') in arr)) arr[$(this).data('login')] = {};
if(! (check in arr[$(this).data('login')])) arr[$(this).data('login')][check] =[];
```

почему в конце `[]` - видимо `.push();` не работает с объектами а только с массивами.